# MonoTouch: Debugging App on Device by autostarting?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have the newest `Mono`, `MonoDevelop` and `MonoTouch` as of this moment, but when I try to debug on a device, I get a dialog suggesting I have an older version?

```
The application has been built and uploaded, or is already up to date.

MonoDevelop cannot start the application automatically because the installed MonoTouch     
version is too old. Please start it by tapping the application icon on the device.
```

Is there an update or tweek needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *current* stable MonoTouch is 5.0.4, which does not support **automatically** starting iOS applications on devices from MonoDevelop.

The *next* stable releases will come from MonoTouch 5.2.x and (if you're using one of the existing **beta**, either 5.1 or 5.2) does support this new (quite handy) feature.

Comment: The above meant the **stable** 5.2.3 is available (5.2 **betas** have been available, with the same feature set, for a few weeks).